Can 2 P-orbitals form both Sigma and Pi bond at same time?
I was reading about Slater Koster Parameters and it talks about interaction between two p orbitals having such a element of $l^2VSP\sigma+(1-l^2)VSP\pi$ where $VSP\sigma$ is interaction energy of a sigma bond, $VSP\pi$ is for a pi bond and $l$ is direction cosines.
Now if I have a particular p orbital arrangement such that it is both linear and sideways overlap, such as say two parallel p orbitals coming towards each other at a 45 degree angle then this would mean that these orbitals are forming both sigma and pi orbitals at same time with 1/2 contribution of both?

This notion of mixed overlap is essentially correct. In fact, the "sigma" bonding in angle-strained systems such as a cyclopropyl ring really involves a mixture of idealized sigma and pi overlaps from the $p$ orbital contributions to the in-plane bonds. As pi overlap is a generally weaker interaction than sigma overlap, we see this energetically as the in-plane bonds in the strained ring being weaker than unstrained, essentially ideal sigma bonds would be.

This might seem irrelevant but when you say pi overlap or 'interaction energy' is less than sigma's. Is that just the magnitude of the said interaction energy? So like would it make sense to say that $E_\sigma < E_\pi$ with sign but |$E_\sigma| > |E_\pi$|?

I said weaker, not less. Weaker implies less in absolute value, which is independent of sign (or, with a vector quantity, direction).
